# Issue in cookies while loading in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am trying to implement a webpage with node.js using hbs engine and express framework... after login i m trying to catch cookies and check in one page as authentication.

```
app.get('/path', function (req, res) {

var cookie= req.cookies.UserId;
    if (cookie != ''||cookie !=null)
      {
    //doing somethig
      }
    else 
      {
     res.redirect("some url");
      }
    }
```

but when i m giving direct url without login this condition get failed and it is not checking for cookies. Initialy cookie is null only still it is failed to redirect..what is the solution for this?

Comment: Is it actually hitting the serverside or is the client just pulling the page from its cache?

Comment: this is server side only.

Comment: *"I am trying to implement a webpage"* That suggested you are using a browser which requests the page...

Comment: actually im using expressparser to get the cookie i wrote one js function to set cookie .

Comment: My point was if you are requesting it from the client, it may NEVER be hitting the serverside code to begin with because it is pulling it from the cache in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Before u redirect try to set maxAge as your domain with your cookie.

Then

```
var cookie= req.cookies.UserId;
```

Example Refer
  Set cookie

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

Take cookie Refer

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.cookies